# Entry permit to italy with polish national visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, airports, italy

I have Polish National Visa valid for one year. D type, multi entry. But I haven't gone to Poland yet, because I had to go to one project, which got rejected its financial part, so I didn't go there yet. 
But I have a project in Italy for one week in April. 
I can't apply for italian visa, because they can't give me any, if I have already valid visa for Poland.
So my question is can I have my first entry to Italy with Polish National Visa.
Can you please give me information regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can go to Italy with your Schengen visa issued by Poland.  If anyone asks why your first entry on that visa is to Italy rather than Poland, you can explain that you applied for the visa in connection with a project that was cancelled or rejected.  Evidence to support that assertion would, of course, increase the likelihood that the official who is asking the question will accept your explanation.

Comment: It's not really a Schengen visa, it's national long-stay visa. They do generally allow the holder to enter other Schengen countries but since this one has no basis anymore (the project will not take place and the OP won't take up residence in Italy), it's a bit tricky.